# Update user.profile with dynamic object in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to update the `user.profile` keeping the old non updated data already present in the `user.profile`.

So, my initial `user.profile` has the following:

```
{
  accountType: 'Student',
  xyz: 'something',
  etc...
}
```

And in my update method I would like to keep those values if not required to be updated, so if I wish to add the following:

```
{
  'xyz': 'something else',
  'bar': 'bar',
  etc...
}
```

I would like to see the updated profile with both object merged and updated.

What I tried to use is `update` and `upsert` but in both cases and all my tests when I try to update the `user.profile` the old data get completely replaced by the new data...

Here is one of my latest try:

```
Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {
  $set: {
    profile: data
  }
},
{ upsert: true });
```

but I also tried:

```
Meteor.users.upsert(this.userId, {
  $set: {
    profile: data
  }
});
```

How can I achieve what I need? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

> The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.

Thus, when you're updating it as `{ $set: { profile: ... } }` it replaces the whole `profile` document.

You should use it like this:

```
$set: {
  'profile.<field_name>': '<field_value>',
  ...
}
```

Here is the code to do that for your case:

```
const $set = {};
_.each(data, (value, key) => {
  $set[`profile.${key}`] = value;
});
Meteor.users.update(this.userId, { $set });
```

Comment: Awesome, I very like the solution. It works as a charm! Cheers!